# Generifying with "super"

Tags: java, generics

I would like to write an Interator like this:

```
class Plant { }
class Tree extends Plant { }
class Maple extends Tree { }

// Iterator class: compiler error on the word "super".
class MyIterator<T super Maple> implements Iterator<T> {
    private int index = 0;
    private List<Maple> list = // Get the list from an external source.

    public T next() {
         Maple maple = list.get(index++);
         // Do some processing.
         return maple;
    }

    // The other methods of Iterator are easy to implement.
}
```

Conceptually, the idea is to have an iterator that looks like it returns Trees or Plants (even though they are always Maples) without writing separate classes for each.

But the compiler doesn't like it when I generify with `T super Maple`; apparently you can only generify a class using `T extends Something`. Does anyone know of a good way to accomplish the same thing?

My motivation for asking is that I have a program that uses interfaces for its API. I want to have one method that returns an iterator of interfaces (for the API) and another that returns an iterator of the implementation classes (for internal use).

Comment: am I reading this wrong?  <T extends Plant> and then `private List<T> list` and `public T next(){ T maple = list.get(index++); return maple;)`

Answer (score 4):

See: [Why is there no lower bound for type parameters?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ107)

Answer (score 3):

If `Maple` is a `Tree` and a `Plant`, because it extends both, what is the point then in the super clause that you want to use? You can, by classical subtype polymorphism assign `Mapple` to `Object`, to `Tree` or to `Plant` references.

Both `? extends T` and `? super T` are wildcards, declared as type arguments to substitute a type parameter `T`.

What you intend to do is define the bound of a type argument not of the type parameter. You can simply declare your type parameter as T, with no bounds, and then, when you use it, you use a wildcard as the type argument.

```
class MyIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> { ... }
```

And when you use it:

```
MyIterator<? super Maple> iter;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so your iterator returns an iterator over maple, but  you want to cast it as an iteratorr over Plant.

Let's pretend (for a moment) that Iterator had a method insertInto(T t) that put an object into the list at the point where the iterator is. . If you cast the iterator as Iterator<Plant> then that would mean that it would be ok to call i.insertInto(myCarrot) - because carrots are plants. But this would violate the types - it would be trying to put a carrot into an underlying list of maples.

In other words, your iterator is *not* an iterator over Plants, it won't take just any old plant as its method arguments, and that's why you can't cast or generify it as such.

Answer (score 0):

It declaring a `super`-bounded type parameter isn't allowed, and [the reasoning is that it is not useful](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ107).

You've managed to stumble on a funny case where, well, it *does* make sense, because if you're implementing a read-only iterator, it *can* be convenient to bound it like that.

The simple option is to just let it be and implement `Iterator<Maple>`, or `Iterator<T>` with some type-checking.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's no ideal way to do this, so I'll suggest two sub-optimal solutions.

The first is a wrapper iterator like this:

```
public class SuperTypeIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
    private final Iterator<? extends E> iter;

    public SuperTypeIterator(Iterator<? extends E> iter) {
        this.iter = iter;
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        return iter.next();
    }

    // And similarly for the other methods of Iterator
}
```

This allows you to change the return type like this:

```
Iterator<Plant> getPlantIterator() {
    return new SuperTypeIterator<Plant>( new MapleIterator() );
}
```

This provides complete type safety at the expense of creating a new object.

An alternative is to use an unchecked cast:

```
Iterator<Plant> getPlantIterator() {
    return (Iterator<Plant>) (Iterator<?>) new MapleIterator();
    // Yes, the double cast is necessary to get it to compile.
}
```

This eliminates the need to create a wrapper object, but at the expense of all type safety.